# React-query query function does not update when a value used inside changes in context

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context, react-query

I am passing the access token used as Bearer token in request headers inside the query function through useContext hook. But when the access token is refreshed after some time, react query keeps using the old access token in the query function.

This is the component using react-query:

```js
const Profile = () => {
  const { fetchUser} = useAppContext();
  const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery(
    ['users'],
    fetchUser
  );

  //...
}
```

This axios intercepter is passed with the context:

```js
 const authFetch = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api/v1',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${state.accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  authFetch.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    async (error) => {
      const status = error?.response?.status;
      if (status === 401) {
        const config = error.config;
        const accessToken = await refreshAccessToken();
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        return axios.request(config);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

(
`await refreshAccessToken()` gets a new access token from the server and updates it in the context state, then returns it back.
)

The function used inside useQuery is also passed with the context:

```js
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    const { data } = await authFetch.get('/users');
    return data;
  };
```

But when the access token is refreshed, useQuery still uses the old access token in the query function. How can I structure my app so that the query uses the new token each time after update?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're closing over the token in your `queryFn`. You're not showing this but I guess `state.accessToken` comes from `useContext` or so.

Generally, everything you use inside the queryFn should be part of the queryKey. So one way to fix it would be to add the token to the queryKey. By combining this with `keepPreviousData: true`, you will keep seeing the old data while the new cache entry is created.

Comment: I do think your approach is appropriate, but every time the token is refreshed, all the queries will be duplicated, leaving queries with old tokens inactive. Is that something which is normal or can it create any problems?

Comment: They will be gargabe collected after being unused for `cacheTime` (default 15 minutes). It shouldn't be a problem. Thinking about it some more: If you have setup an axios interceptor, how does it access react context? I think I'm missing the full picture here. Why not store the token _outside_ of react and just directly access it the request interceptor?

Comment: How would I go about storing the token outside react and updating it from inside react at login and refresh?

Comment: Update: So I used two variables to store the tokens outside of the provider component. I update them directly by assigning new values in register and refresh functions. and use them directly inside the axios instance. I wanted to ask if there will be any side effects of not using a state to store and update them?

Comment: @TkDodo your suggestion of adding the token to the key seems to be working for me (at least after a small test) but it's having the effect of reloading the queries when the token is updated. Is there an approach to ensure the latest token is used for future fetches (e.g. invalidations) but that doesn't immediately cause a refresh?